# How to download and load ML model using sentence transformer with dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, sentence-transformers

We dont want to download the model at runtime. Instead of that, it should be downloaded at the time of dock build.

So,what's the command for downloading the model using sentence transformer through docker file?

And if we able to download it then how we can load it using the same library inside the container/app.py

Your response will be really helpful for me. Please let me know if anybody know solution for the same.

Answer (score 3):

What I do

For example :

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN python -c 'from transformers import AutoTokenizer; AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")'
RUN python -c 'from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM; AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")'
```

With this example the model is going to be downloaded in the cache folder.
Also you can change the path:

```
export TRANSFORMERS_CACHE=
```

or you can define the folder cache with cache_dir
for example:

```
AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M",cache_dir="./model")
```

The idea is to download the model using python itself.

A good approach is to use with multi-stages docker.